# Why do I get double calls to the previewKeyDown() function in c#

Tags: c#

I use the previewKeyDown() function for some controls in my project but they always get called twice for each key press. Anyone who knows how to solve this?

And is there anyway to do a global keylistener in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WebBrowser control I think has a bug, it fires that twice no matter what.  I solved it via what I consider a hack, but it works.  :)  Mines in VB, but you get the gist of it, basically make a bool in your form's scope and use it to negate one of the two events that are fired:

```
    Private _skipPreviewKeyDown As Boolean = False
Private Sub WebBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.PreviewKeyDown

    If _skipPreviewKeyDown = True Then
        _skipPreviewKeyDown = False
        Exit Sub
    Else
        _skipPreviewKeyDown = True
    End If

    'Select Case e.KeyDa
    MsgBox(e.KeyValue)

End Sub
```

Comment: Here, I found someone who did the same thing in C# so you can just copy and paste from there, it appears this has been around a while, perhaps it's by design but I wouldn't think so since the event says KeyDown but it fires when the Key comes up also: 

 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f83d3d71-ea3e-4b18-a610-30a91fae060e/

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one. It definitely seems to get called twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using KeyUp event instead. I think the key repeat is causing you problem.

Comment: Could be but it doesn't look like it. I tried to print some logs for each event I got and it's always 2 events no mater how fast I press. And when I keep the button pressed down I get 2 events and then it takes a while (about 1/2 sec) before I start receiving more events (which probably is from key repeat) 

KeyUp might have solved my problem but I'm unfortunately using the webbrowser which don't support keyup.